# Changes To FormGroup.value edit the actual formGroup controls

Tags: angular, formgroups

I have a formGroup with about 20 controls. 2 of these are date objects.

I want to convert the entire formGroup to an object with the 2 date controls converted to an `ISOString`

However when I convert the dates, the original formGroup's control values get updated as well. Any ideas how I can convert the properties of `formGroup.value` and modify that object without affecting the original?

```
prepareParams():ReportRequest{
  let query = this.reportForm.value
  if(query.startDate)
    query.startDate = this.reportForm.get('startDate')?.value.toISOString()
  if(query.endDate)
    query.endDate = this.reportForm.get('endDate')?.value.toISOString()
  return query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the value object of the form with the spread operator or with `Object.assign`. Otherwise your updating the value of your form, since the variable `query` will be just another reference to the original object.

Something like this:

```
prepareParams():ReportRequest{
  let query = { ...this.reportForm.value };
  if(query.startDate)
    query.startDate = this.reportForm.get('startDate')?.value.toISOString()
  if(query.endDate)
    query.endDate = this.reportForm.get('endDate')?.value.toISOString()
  return query
}
```

or this:

```
prepareParams():ReportRequest{
  let query = Object.assign({}, this.reportForm.value);
  if(query.startDate)
    query.startDate = this.reportForm.get('startDate')?.value.toISOString()
  if(query.endDate)
    query.endDate = this.reportForm.get('endDate')?.value.toISOString()
  return query
}
```